# Переписать в массив элементы матрицы, больше x C++

Tags: c++

Вот уже час ломаю голову как из матрицы `A` переписать элементы в массив `B` которые будут больше заданного `x`

Получилось сделать только кратное определенному числу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    std::default_random_engine gen{ std::random_device()() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(-10, 10);
    int n, m; std::cout << "N, M = "; std::cin >> n >> m;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> A(n, std::vector<int>(n));
    std::vector<int> d;
    for (auto& Row : A) {
        std::generate(Row.begin(), Row.end(), [&dist, &gen] { return dist(gen); });
        std::copy(Row.begin(), Row.end(), std::ostream_iterator <int>(std::cout, "\t"));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    int AA; std::cout << "Значение = "; std::cin >> AA;
    for (auto& Row : A)
        for (auto& elem : Row)
            if (elem % AA == 0) d.push_back(elem);
    std::cout << "Массив: ";
    std::copy(d.begin(), d.end(), std::ostream_iterator <int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

По факту код даже не мой, но если у кого есть идеи пишите

Comment: что за х? Это какое то заданное число? И в приведенном коде есть ошибка уже при объявлении вектора векторов.

Comment: да x это заданое число, ошибок нет - код рабочий

Comment: по крайней мере у меня он запустился и работал

Comment: Код работает. Как работает, что делает, как делает? Вы задаете  два размера, а используете только один. У вас   `n` векторов с таким же размером. Я еще не говорю, что используете два алгоритма для  инициализации и вывода, когда можно одним проходом и инициализировать и выводить.

Comment: А  формулировка вопроса не такая качественная, чтобы можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Я в c++ не сильно разбираюсь и это не совсем моя сфера, я дал кусочек кода чтобы может что-то пришло в голову. Сообственно говоря поэтому и пишу сюда чтобы узнать как это сделать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118728/discussion-between-ar-hovsepyan-and-kowl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто догадываюсь, что вам нужно это:

```
std::default_random_engine gen{ std::random_device()() };
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(-10, 10);
int n, m; std::cout << "N, M = "; std::cin >> n >> m;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> A(n, std::vector<int>(m));
std::vector<int> d;
for (auto& Row : A) {
    //выполнить за один проход
    std::generate(Row.begin(), Row.end(),
        [&dist, &gen] { 
            int t = dist(gen);
            std::cout << t << '\t';
            return t; });        
    std::cout << '\n';
}
int AA; 
std::cout << "Value ";
std::cin >> AA;
auto greater_thanx = [&AA](int a) { return a > AA; };      
std::cout << "Result array: ";
for (const auto& Row : A)
    std::copy_if(Row.begin(), Row.end(), std::back_inserter(d), greater_thanx);
//можем сортировать и убрать повторяющийся элементы (если нужно)
std::sort(d.begin(), d.end());
d.erase(std::unique(d.begin(), d.end()), d.end());
std::copy(d.begin(), d.end(), std::ostream_iterator <int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: да всё верно, спасибо Вам большое